# Using command with optional arguments inside tikzcd arrows

Tags: tikz-cd, optional-arguments

I have defined a command for the jacobian matrix, such as follows

```
\newcommand{\Jacobian}[2][]{\operatorname{J}_{#1}{#2}}
```

The problem comes if I try to use it inside a `tikzcd` arrow, probably because of problems with interepreting the brackets. I want to write something like this:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
    \mathbb{R}^{2} \arrow[r,"\Jacobian[p]{f}"] &
    \mathbb{R}^{2}
\end{tikzcd}
```

And have an output as if I had typed

```
\begin{tikzcd}
    \mathbb{R}^{2} \ar[r, "\operatorname{J}_{p}{f}"] &
    \mathbb{R}^{2}
\end{tikzcd}
```

But if I try this, compilation fails with

```
ERROR: Argument of \tikz@quote@@parser has an extra }.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.152     \end{tikzcd}

--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
```

I tried putting braces in some reasonable places without success.

Answer (score 2):

You have to enclose the whole command in braces *inside* the quotes.

```
\begin{tikzcd}
    \mathbb{R}^{2} \arrow[r,"{\Jacobian[p]{f}}"] &
    \mathbb{R}^{2}
\end{tikzcd}
```

Comment: You should edit your question instead of posting an answer. If there is now an answer, many people will ignore your question.